Why did changing MinGW path for Qt kits resolve "The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library" error?
My problem
I encountered a strange issue while compiling a program from Stanford's CS106B course using Qt. When I initially selected a MinGW-based kit in Qt, I got the following error:

"Welcome.exe - Entry Point Not Found
The procedure entry point _ZNSt5seekgEST4fposl9_MbstateE could not be located in the dynamic link library C:\Users\MR\Desktop\CS106B\CS106\Welcome\Welcome.exe."

I've tried:

Adding both MinGW related paths from the Qt directory to the system environment variables and moved them to the highest priority in the PATH order. However, even after this adjustment, I still encountered the same error when running the program.

After some troubleshooting, I noticed an option in the lower-left corner of the Qt interface to switch kits. I found that I had two very similar MinGW kits available. After switching to the other kit, the program compiled and ran successfully without any issues.


However, I'm unsure why this change fixed the problem. The two kits seem almost identical except for their paths.
What is the difference between these two MinGW kits, and why did switching them resolve the compilation error?

Both kits' information:

The kit that does not work:

The exact compiler info: gcc version 13.2.0 (Rev3, Built by MSYS2 project)
The modified kit that works:

The exact compiler info: gcc version 13.1.0 (x86_64-posix-seh-rev1, Built by MinGW-Builds project)


More Info About My Qt

Installed kits as shown in Qt Creator:


My Qt version:
Since I installed it through Anaconda, it seems that I have two versions of Qt?




Consider also the Qt Forum, and share the answer here if you get a detailed one to benefit future readers. Here's a direct search link: Qt Forum — "The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library". Might not work unless you log in.

As far as I know, The used compiler needs to match the one Qt was built with. You installed the Qt 6.8.0 MinGW 13.1.0 64-bit kit, which means it was built with MinGW 13.1.0 64-bit, so that's the compiler to use with. The other kit (which does not work) is also Qt 6.8.0 MinGW 64-bit, and the only Qt 6.8.0 that was built with MinGW, is Qt 6.8.0 MinGW 13.1.0 64-bit, but the compiler used in that kit is MinGW 13.2.0, so there goes the incompatibility.

The only thing I am not familiar with is "Built by [X]" part, which is also different for both compilers. So, I don't feel like posting an answer, even though I don't think it matters here since even the versions do not match.
